# Animating button state in react between two components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation

I'm having a bit trouble with an animation that I want to make in React.
Currently, I have 2 solutions, but I think that should be a better way to do it.

**Let me explain:**

[image]

Like in the gif above, I have two components, the first one is a title with a plus (note that this plus could not be centered, this depends on the title size), the second one is a section with a centered black plus;

What I need to do is: When the second section hits the first plus, animate the second button, transforming the white plus into the black one.

### Solutions that I've imagined:

- Calculate the distance of the white plus when I click him, then pass the distance to the second section via `redux`. Why I can't do it? Because there's a way to open the section via route;
- Send the first white button to the second section when I click him, but Idk how to do it [I've searched a lot about it, no luck :(];

### Code

#### - First component with white Button

```
  render() {
    const {
      hide,
      changing,
      currentTitle,
      currentSubtitle,
      currentNumbers,
    } = this.state;
    const classNames = [ 'video__overlay', hide ? ' video__overlay--hidden' : '', changing ? ' video__overlay--off' : '', ].join('');

    return (
      <div className={`${classNames}`}>
        <small className="video__quantity" onAnimationEnd={this._animationHandler}>{this._breakLetters(currentNumbers)}</small>

        <div className="video__title-box">
          <h1 className="video__title"> {this._breakLetters(currentTitle)}</h1> // <--- The title that I was talking about

           {this.props.haveDetails && (
             <div className="video__plus">
               <Link to={`/info/${this.props.slug}`}>
                 <Isvg src="/assets/images/plus.svg" className="video__plus-svg" />
               </Link>
             </div>
           )}
         </div>

      <small className="video__subtitle" onAnimationEnd={this._animationHandler}>{this._breakLetters(currentSubtitle)}</small>
    </div>
);
```

}

#### - Second Component with Black Button

```
  render() {
    const detailsClass = [ 'details', this.state.close ? ' details--out' : '', this.props.expanded ? ' details--noscroll' : '', ].join('');
    const contentClass = [ 'details__content', this.props.changing ? ' details__content--out' : '', ].join('');

    return (
      <div className={detailsClass} onWheel={this._handleWheel} onAnimationEnd={this._handleAnimation} ref="details">
        <div className={contentClass}>
          <div className="details__close-btn" onClick={this._handleClose}>
            <Isvg src="/assets/images/plus-variant.svg" />
        </div>

        <DetailsInfo />
        <DetailsStills images={this.props.images} subtitle={this.props.description} />
        <DetailsContinue />
      </div>
    </div>
   );
 }
```

Comment: Add your code please =)

Comment: @NatDavydova code added!